# Check if class is present if else add height to a div

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is check if class exist. If present add height by 'X' px in another class if not add height by 'Y' px

Not using Jquery. And it should be supported in IE8. `document.getElementsByClassName` is not supported in IE8 so used `className.match` but then again it started to get longer. My code below does not go past the 3rd

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/gunomu/1/edit)

Any one with a short IE8 friendly code?

```
window.onload = window.onresize = function heightResize () {
var browserHeight = window.innerHeight;
var present=document.getElementsByTagName('p');
alert(present.length);
 for (var i=0; i<present.length; i++) {
  if (present[i].className.match(/\bbuttons-container\b/))
       {
 alert("Yes Present");
 document.getElementsByClassName("boxcontent")[0].style.height = browserHeight -150 + "px";
       } else {
alert("Not Present");
document.getElementsByClassName("boxcontent")[0].style.height = browserHeight -200 + "px";
              }

              }

              };
```

HTML

```
 <p>
First Para
 </p>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <p>
Second Paragraph
    </p>
    <div  id ="overlay_modal" class="boxcontent">
      Output
    </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
   </table>

  <p>
Third Para
  </p>
   <p class="buttons-container">
Buttons
   </p>
```

Comment: I have to question why you would resize the height of your boxContent on each of your iterations, would it not be better to set a bool flag to true when you found a match (and break out of the for loop), and change the height after the for loop?

Comment: Hi! Icepickle, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, i could make this version of it:

```
function getElementsByTagClassName(tag, className) {
  var ret = [], tags = document.getElementsByTagName(tag), i, len, item;
  for (i = 0, len = tags.length; i < len; i++) {
    item = tags[i];
    if (item.className.match("\\b" + className)) {
      ret.push(item);
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

function heightResize() {
  var browserHeight = parseInt(window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight), 
      paragraphs, found = false, boxcontent, i, len, elem;

  paragraphs = getElementsByTagClassName('p', 'buttons-container');
  found = paragraphs && paragraphs.length;
  boxcontent = getElementsByTagClassName('div', 'boxcontent');
  if (boxcontent && boxcontent.length) {
    for (i = 0, len = boxcontent.length; i < len; i++) {
      elem = boxcontent[i];
      if (found) {
          elem.style.height = (browserHeight - 150 > 0 ? browserHeight - 150 : 0) + 'px';
      } else {
          elem.style.height = (browserHeight - 200 > 0 ? browserHeight - 200 : 0) + 'px';
      }
      alert(elem.style.height);
    }
  }
}

window.onload = window.onresize = heightResize;
```

You could find the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/ebrknr3d/), and an [embedded version](http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/ebrknr3d/embedded/result/) (to test in IE8 here)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I think I will use jquery purely because it might be easier to manage. Your code works perfectly fine.. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 does indeed not support `document.getElementsByClassName` but `querySelectorAll` is supported, albeit only with IE8's limited css support.

This allows you to get the elements with a given class like

```
document.querySelectorAll('.classname');
```

If you really need to select the elements "without" the class (as opposed to giving them a different class) you could select all `<p>` tags, then select all tags with the class and see which ones match.

Keep in mind that querySelectorAll returns a NodeList, not an Array. It looks like an array (and can be looped over) but it doesn't have the Array methods.

Comment: If it's just for this problem I'd advise against it. If you've got more DOM manipulations that need to work in older browsers it's probably the way to go, but if it's a very limited amount jQuery isn't really worth it.